# Apache2 ErrorLog unexpected behavior

Tags: linux, apache, webserver, apache2, ubuntu-16.04

I'm really in the dark after Googling my problem for the past few hours.

**My problem:**
I run an Apache2 webserver (Ubuntu Server 16.04) with multiple Virtual Hosts. Everything works fine but one thing: my error logs.
In my Virtual Host file I have set: ErrorLog /var/log/sitename/error_test.log

The thing is, only some parts of the errors are written there. The 'other half' (so to speak) of the errors are getting written to the default Apache logfile: /var/log/apache2/error.log

Apache seems to have the correct permissions because it creates the logfile itself in the correct directory after I restart the apache2 service.

Because I have several websites, I would like to seperate the logfiles of course. But I can't seem to get this to work.

**What I've already tried:**

- Check permissions (even 777 the whole directory), but that doesn't seem the problem because some errors are getting written in the designated logfile.
- Changing the LogLevel to info/warn/error/debug etc. This resulted in some additional info that I got in my logfile when I set it to 'debug', but still the most important information went to the default logfile.
- Different location for the logfile (/home/username) -> same result
- Changed the Apache default user/group -> same result

**Relevant info:**

Virtual host file:

```
   ServerName servername
   DocumentRoot /var/www/sitename/htdocs/

   LogLevel debug

   ErrorLog "/var/log/sitename/error_test.log"
   CustomLog "/var/log/sitename/custom_test.log" combined

   ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/www/sitename/scripts/

   ReWriteEngine on
   ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)

   ReWriteRule .* -[F]

</VirtualHost>
```

error_test.log:

```
[authz_core:debug] [pid 3157:tid 140305256847104] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client IP-ADDRESS] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
```

Default Apache2 logfile:

```
[pid 3232:tid 140305620424576] (13)Permission denied: AH01241: exec of '/var/www/sitename/scripts/errorgenerator.pl' failed
```

Please note that the "Permission denied" message in the default Apache2 file is generated by me to test the logfile. This is the message that I want to have in my custom set ErrorLog.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I feel like an idiot, but just after posting my problem here I stumbled upon this thread: [Errors for virtual host are not written to specified ErrorLog, but to default error_log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28450175/errors-for-virtual-host-are-not-written-to-specified-errorlog-but-to-default-er?rq=1)

Which pushed me in the right direction. The solution:

```
sudo a2dismod mpm_event
sudo a2enmod mpm_prefork
sudo a2enmod cgi
sudo service apache2 restart
```

There seems to be a bug in the default cgi handler of Apache (mod_cgid) that causes this behaviour. See: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14090

Switch to mod_cgi (which you do with the above commands) and the errors are written to the ErrorLog stated in the Virtual Host...